# I cannt make Android Studio Design View to work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to install Android Studio on my personal laptops. The problem is that I cannot make design view work. When I try to drag any widgets to the design, nothing happens. I've tried even older versions of Android Studio but the problem is the same on two laptops (win7 & 10). What could be wrong?

Highlights are the buttons

[image: img1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
    xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"; 
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"> 
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Could you show us the xml code for the layout?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: I've added the code to the question instead for ease of viewing. If this is all the xml code, then your button is not actually in the layout. You can tell because in between the `>` of the layout and the end tag, there is nothing. I don't drag components in very often, so I type them in. Try inserting this small section in between the tags: `<Button android:id="@+id/button/>` Then look at the graphical layout and try to work with it.

Comment: sorry, not working :(

Comment: I made a little mistake. change `<Button android:id="@+id/button/>` to `<Button android:id="@+id/button"/>` Also try specifying the size of the button: `<Button android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>` Just checking, but this should be in between `tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">` and  
`</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`

Comment: Not working again..it's blank.

Comment: Please show me your build.gradle code

Comment: You have a red circle in the top right corner that includes errors that need to be fixed first